# Javascript Azure Function to send email using SendGrid

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-functions, sendgrid

I want to send emails from an Azure function (Javascript) using SendGrid. I have done the following

1. created a new AppSettings for SendGrid API Key
2. SendGrid output binding set of Azure Function
3. Following is my Azure Function

```
    module.exports = function (context, myQueueItem) {
var message = {
         "personalizations": [ { "to": [ { "email": "testto@test.com" } ] } ],
        from: { email: "testfrom@test.com" },        
        subject: "Azure news",
        content: [{
            type: 'text/plain',
            value: myQueueItem
        }]
    };
    context.done(null, message);
};
```

But email is not getting send. Please provide some pointers

Comment: Could you provide your `SendGrid` binding?

Comment: Are there any errors returned by the API? I created a short PowerShell script for doing the same https://gist.github.com/kimpihlstrom/145304ebb00311270b3c6f7a99d4c606. Check it out, in case it's of any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I test and face the same problem with you initially.

Please change to **context.done(null, {message});**

You could try to use the following code:

```
module.exports = function (context, order) {    
    context.log(order);
    var message = {
         "personalizations": [ { "to": [ { "email": "testto@gmail.com" } ] } ],
        from: { email: "testfrom@gmail.com" },        
        subject: "Azure news",
        content: [{
            type: 'text/plain',
            value: order
        }]
    };

    context.done(null, {message});
};
```

And the funtion.json file is:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "queueTrigger",
      "name": "order",
      "direction": "in",
      "queueName": "samples-orders"
    },
    {
      "type": "sendGrid",
      "name": "message",
      "direction": "out",
      "apiKey": "mysendgridkey",
      "from": "testfrom@gmail.com",
      "to": "testto@gmail.com"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

Here I use the Gmail, so I also **Allow less secure apps: ON**

[image]

Click this [link](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps), you could configure it.

Comment: How to add an attachment to the email. Can you please give an example